# How to run a whole function before iterating to the next index (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, closures

I am trying to run a function where I open a new window to a url and close the new window after 1.5 seconds. I am trying to loop and execute this 3 times. However, the code open all three new windows together and then performs the timeout. I want the next window to open only once the previous one has closed.

```
function test(url){
  let a = window.open(url);
  a.focus();
  setTimeout(()=>{
    a.close();
  }, 1500);
};

const repl = 'mysite.com';

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  test(repl);
}
```

Comment: Use a callback to 'do something else' *after* the timeout, eg. `function test(url, onClosed) { ... setTimeout(() => { a.close(); onClosed(); } }`. Then use that callback to chain calls (eg. call the next `test` function), instead of the loop. Alternatively, see Promises, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one to run after the other, when the other one is done, call the next. For example, something like this

```
const reps = 3;
let i = 0;
function test(url){
  let a = window.open(url);
  a.focus();
  setTimeout(()=>{
    a.close();
    i++;
    if (i < 3) {
      test(url);
    }
  }, 1500);
};

const repl = 'mysite.com';
test(repl);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use For loop syntax, or would I be better off checking out Async / Await, Promises, or Callbacks? Anyway, awesome code! This works 

Comment: A for loop is not compatible with handling asynchronous logic.  @GodComplex

Comment: @GodComplex You could use a for loop syntax if you were inside an async function, and your function returned a promise. So when that promise was solved, you'd go to the next iteration

Comment: @Taplar It is when using `async-await`, so @GodComplex yes, checking out `async-await` is highly recommended

Answer (score -1):

You can use asynch library where you will find many methods like foreach, every. You can execute task in series as well as in parallel for running task synchronously you can use foreachlimit with limit 1 where a single task will be complete first then the next iteration starts.

Comment: Do you have an example? Why is a library needed or beneficial here?